# Google page speed error message: Lighthouse returned error: FAILED_DOCUMENT_REQUE

Tags: google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I got this error message from google page speed test. A few months ago it was working fine.
Lighthouse returned error: FAILED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST. Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the page you requested. Make sure you are testing the correct URL and that the server is properly responding to all requests. net::ERR_CONNECTION_FAILED.
https://www.inlineortho.com.au

Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue, but the site I am testing is hidden from public access, it's only on white-list basis.

Answer (score 1):

Google can't crawl because your website is slow. That is why you're getting this error.

Comment: Please make your answer better by providing some solid materials.

Comment: This is definitely not the correct answer.  My site loads very fast and is getting this issue.  I strongly suspects it's related to caching or image lazy loading.  I noticed that I was getting this error after enabling a caching plugin and a lazy loading plugin in WordPress.